# Integral solution / simplification

Tags: calculus, integration

I am encountering difficulty in solving the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^\infty(1-x)^{a_2-1}x^{a_1-1}dx$$

Could you suggest a substitution using the sum of an infinite geometric/Taylor or other progression series which would help in evaluating this mathematical expression?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I expect you want to integrate from $0$ to $1$, not $0$ to $\infty$.  I suggest looking at the Wikipedia article about the [beta function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Comment: Is the upper bound of your integration correct?

Answer (score 0):

If, as André Nicolas suggested in his comment, you looked at the Wikipedia page and in particular at what is said about the incomplete beta function, you arrived to $$I=\int(1-x)^{a_2-1}x^{a_1-1}dx=\frac{({a_1}+{a_2}) B_x({a_1},{a_2}+1)-x^{{a_1}}
   (1-x)^{{a_2}}}{{a_2}}$$ So,$$I_t=\int_0^t(1-x)^{a_2-1}x^{a_1-1}dx=B_t({a_1},{a_2})$$  If $t=1$, the result simplifies to $$\frac{\Gamma ({a_1})~~ \Gamma ({a_2})}{\Gamma ({a_1}+{a_2})}$$